# argument of \@gobble has an extra }

Tags: fonts

On removing authors affiliation from my research paper I got an error "`argument of \@gobble has an extra }.` "
Help me how to fix it.

```
\documentclass{svjour3} 
\begin{document} 
\title{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX} 
\titlerunning{XXXXXXXX} % if too long for running head 
\maketitle 
\begin{abstract} 
  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  \keywords{xx \and xxx \and xxx \and xxx \and xxxx \and xxx} 
\end{abstract} 
\section{Introduction}\label{sec:Introduction} 
 xxxxxxxx 
\section{Previous Work} \label{sec:PreviousWork} 
xxxxx
\end{document} % end of file
```

Comment: Basically impossible unless you give us some code. Preferably a compile (but minimal) document that we can compile on out own systems.

Comment: so somewhere in some file we haven't seen some command has an incorrect matching of `{` and `}`.

Comment: @ daleif research paper is about to submit in a journal and confidential. problem is related to \maketitle and if I remove this tag.. pdf did not generate title page

Comment: we are not interested in the words, make a copy of the paper, then if the error is in maketitle you can presumably delete the entire content of the paper after that, and change every letter in the title to `x`. If the problem still occurs, post the resulting document into the question.

Comment: @ daleif should i send you my paper with whole latex packages. Can you help me in this way.

Comment: may be some problem with any latex package that is not compatible with other when I remove the author tags and other information related to it.

Comment: the short document is given below: \documentclass{svjour3}

\begin{document}

\title{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}

\titlerunning{XXXXXXXX}        % if too long for running head

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\keywords{xx \and xxx \and xxx \and xxx \and xxxx \and xxx}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:Introduction}
xxxxxxxx

\section{Previous Work} \label{sec:PreviousWork}

xxxxx
\end{document}
% end of file

Answer (score 6):

use an `\author`:

```
\documentclass{svjour3} 
    \title{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX} 
    \titlerunning{XXXXXXXX} % if too long for running head 
\author{}%%%%%%%%
\begin{document} 
\maketitle
[...]
```